# How can I export vpython pictures

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, export, vpython

I wanted to export the raw images produced using vpython on my HDD. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer is to use a screen capture tool, which most operating systems offer.

As of this week (November 2018) there's a new option in GlowScript VPython, scene.capture(filename), which will also be available in the next release of VPython 7.

Here's the documentation:

capture(filename) Sends to your Download folder a png screen shot of the canvas. If filename is the string "boxes" or "boxes.png" the file will be named "boxes.png". (Not yet available in VPython 7.)

Comment: This is kind of useless.  It requires user interaction (pops up an interactive SaveAs...)  It does not work in headless environment, or in a docker image that does not have a browser installed.

Comment: I don't fully understand. In both VPython 7 and Web VPython scene.capture(name) does NOT invoke a popup; it just sends the image to the download folder. (I can understand however that there could be problems with special invironments.)

Comment: ok i guess it depends on the browser settings